# Terminal won't find any file/directory with the suffix "~/." or "~/"

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, command-line

my terminal isn't capable of finding any file or directory if I type in the name of the file or directory which start with "~/." or "~/".

I have OS El Capitan, XCode 8 is installed, so is XCode Command Lines Tools.

Edit

As requested, this is the full command line I put( I tried several):

```
   cd ~/.bash_profile_common
   cd ~/usr
   cd ~/local
   cd ~/bin
```

And finder doesn't seem to find them either.

After typing

```
   echo $HOME
```

I get

```
   /Users/myname
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` (tilde) expands to the value of the variable `HOME` which is set by the process `login` or to the value set in one of your shell's config files.

From the man pages:

> **HOME** - The home directory of the current user; the default argument for the cd builtin command. The value of this variable is also used when performing tilde expansion.
>
> **Tilde Expansion** - If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the characters preceding  the first unquoted  slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a ***tilde-prefix***. If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible ***login name***. If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the shell parameter **HOME**. If **HOME** is unset, the home directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead. Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated with the specified login name.

In your case (assuming you have not changed `HOME`), using `~/bin`, `~/usr`, `~/local` is expanding them to `/Users/myname/bin`, `/Users/myname/usr`, `/Users/myname/local`.

If what you want is in the root folder of your system, don't put the `~` (leave just `/` at the front).

References: [man page for bash](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html)/`man bash`

Comment: I see my mistake. It now definitely works, thank you! But it is still unable to find the bash_profile_common file,what could I do!

Comment: @Edward that is not a standard file. Did you create it?

Comment: No, I never created. It was suggested that I should edit it, due to some compilation  problems. I assumed it would be created during the installation of the compiler. I think I will head towards stackoverflow forum and ask if it's normal that I am unable to find this file.

Comment: Where was that suggestion - you are going to need to quote it for any chance that your question won't be closed on SO and even then I expect it his off topic there.

Comment: @edward please ask a new question about the bash_profile_common thing. Be sure to include links etc to the instructions you are following. Or just use `~/.bash_profile` instead :-)

Comment: @Edward bash and the finder will hide any file that begins with a '.' (unix conventions) use ls -a to list from the bash prompt

Answer (score -1):

You can also find a good explanation of the standard Unix directory layout with `man hier` at the shell prompt.